# Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
$land = $_POST['land'];
$resultxax = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where land = '$land'") or die(mysql_error());
$number=mysql_num_rows($resultxax);
echo $number;
```

Why do I get an error?

`$land` is a value of a multiselect dropdownbox.

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" id="e9"multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <?php include("../country_dropdown.php");
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: If $land is a value of a multiselect dropdownbox, then it's an array (and can't simply be treated as a string), and may contain multiple values, so your query needs to allow for that

Comment: Also, using mysql is deprecated. You will want to start using mysqli or PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: true, and print_r($land); before query

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Remember to mark an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$arrayVal = join(',',$land);  
$resultxax = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where land IN ('$arrayVal')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Don't forget that strings need quoting in SQL statements

Comment: when i try that i get this... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''AX'' at line 1

Comment: `$arrayVal = join("','",$land);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$resultxax = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where land = '".$land."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

or this:

```
$resultxax = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where land = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($land) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Let us know if it works :)

Comment: Neither will help with $land being an array rather than a string

Comment: $land is an array - that needs to be taken into consideration

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the feedback. (Sorry for putting this as answer - don't have enough reputation yet...)

Comment: @Anna, you can delete your answer if you don't feel it should be here anymore.

Answer (score -3):

If you had shown us the HTML form which created the POST then we would have noticed that you'd named the element as land[].

Comment: Should be a comment, and it isn't necessary to see the html because OP specifically mentions that it's a multiselect dropdownbox

Comment: @MarkBaker it would be nice to see the multiselect `name` attribute